# Getting components to align

Tags: android, layout

[image]I have an Android app that has multiple spinners and check boxes in the layout of a certain activity. I have created Linear Layouts for each pair of components and want them to align vertically in the view. Obviously the left components align to the left border. But the right components are not aligned giving the layout a really poor appearance. I want my right side components to align down the center of the view. Is there a way to do this?

I need the solution to work across any screen size, so I have avoided using a brute force layout_width value suck as 150dp. The xml file below is only part of the file. It repeats basically the same two component Linear Layout all the way down.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sign_configuration_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/sign_config_toolbar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_layout_1">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/sign_type_spinner"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Spinner>
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/sign_size_spinner"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Spinner>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_layout_2">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/radar_type_spinner"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Spinner>
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/min_speed_spinner"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Spinner>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to add your layout XML to the post and you should also add a screenshot of what it now looks like and what it shouild look like. A picture is better than 1000 words!

Comment: Please post a picture, its hard to understand what result you want to achieve and what you have so far.

Comment: I had a heck of a time getting this thing to post the code and the image, but finally here they are. As you can see, the right side components are not aligned as the left side components vary in width. I thought the weightSum and layout_weight would make them equal sized but something is not working as I thought it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each of the layouts set: `android:layout_width="0dp"` for the spinners and checkboxes because the width will be set according to the `layout_weight` attribute:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_layout_2">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/radar_type_spinner"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Spinner>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/min_speed_spinner"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.